# Navigation drawer, ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I would customize the navigation drawer. I used an example that I found on stackoverflow in an other thread. 
The code is a copy and paste, but when run the app in the logcat obtain an exception: "ResourceNotFoundException". 
Below paste a piece of logcat

```
08-02 20:06:26.367: E/AndroidRuntime(6084): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
08-02 20:06:26.367: E/AndroidRuntime(6084):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
08-02 20:06:26.367: E/AndroidRuntime(6084):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3837)
08-02 20:06:26.367: E/AndroidRuntime(6084):     at it.ustation.DrawerAdapter.getView(DrawerAdapter.java:81)
08-02 20:06:26.367: E/AndroidRuntime(6084):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
....
```

The code of my adapter is

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListNavigationItemModel>{

public DrawerAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
}

public void addHeader(int title) {
    add(new ListNavigationItemModel(title, -1, true));
}

public void addItem(int title, int icon) {
    add(new ListNavigationItemModel(title, icon, false));
}

public void addItem(ListNavigationItemModel itemModel) {
    add(itemModel);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; 
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isHeader ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return !getItem(position).isHeader;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public final TextView textHolder;
    public final ImageView imageHolder;

    public ViewHolder(TextView text1, ImageView image1) {
        this.textHolder = text1;
        this.imageHolder = image1;
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ListNavigationItemModel item = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        int layout = R.layout.list_item_drawer;
        if (item.isHeader)
            layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_header;

        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layout, null);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nd_title);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.nd_thumb_image);
        view.setTag(new ViewHolder(text1, image1));
    }

    if (holder == null && view != null) {
        Object tag = view.getTag();
        if (tag instanceof ViewHolder) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) tag;
        }
    }

    if (item != null && holder != null) {
        if (holder.textHolder != null)
            holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);

        if (holder.imageHolder != null) {
            if (item.iconRes > 0) {
                holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(item.iconRes);
            } else {
                holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

and the model is

```
public class ListNavigationItemModel {

public int title;
public int iconRes;
public boolean isHeader;

public ListNavigationItemModel(int title, int iconRes, boolean header) {
    this.title = title;
    this.iconRes = iconRes;
    this.isHeader = header;
}

public ListNavigationItemModel(int title, int iconRes) {
    this(title, iconRes, false);
}
 }
```

and the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nd_thumb_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail_desc"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_save" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nd_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nd_thumb_image"
    android:text="@string/c_desc"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and this is the code for add each item on adapter. mPlanetTitles is an array string.

```
for (String item : mPlanetTitles) {

        int id_menu_one = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string", this.getPackageName());
        int id_menu_one_icons = getResources().getIdentifier(menuOneIcons[oneIcons], "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        ListNavigationItemModel mItem = new ListNavigationItemModel(id_menu_one, id_menu_one_icons);
        mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
        oneIcons++;
    }
```

Comment: what is line 81 in `DrawerAdapter.java`? what is `item.title`. Is it a string?

Comment: The line 81 in DrawerAdapter is `holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);`

Comment: is `item.title` a string and not an integer?

Comment: `item.title` is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments `item.title` is an integer

So use

```
    holder.textHolder.setText(String.valueOf(item.title));
```

what is wrong?

```
    public final void setText (int resid)
```

`setText` looks for an resource id which is integer. which is not there. Hence you get `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Instead you should use the seText with CharSequence as param

`public final void setText (CharSequence text)`

Added in API level 1

Sets the string value of the TextView. TextView does not accept HTML-like formatting, which you can do with text strings in XML resource files. To style your strings, attach android.text.style.* objects to a SpannableString, or see the Available Resource Types documentation for an example of setting formatted text in the XML resource file.

`public static String valueOf(int i)`

Returns the string representation of the int argument.
The representation is exactly the one returned by the Integer.toString method of one argument.

Comment: if use `String.valueOf(item.title)`, the app doesn't crash, but i show `0` for each item.

Comment: check your `item.title` value its is 0. But your problem is solved. Check your `item.title` and how you set the value. Something will be wrong setting the value.

Comment: I edited my code above, the code add each item on adapter. where's the error?? I think that's correct. I doesn't understand.

Comment: @reb2awrl i am sure it has nothing to do with the above change i suggested. its hard to tell what wrong. I suggest you put a break point and try debugging. If its 0 check the position and `item.value`. add `Log.i("title is",""+item.title)` before you set the text. If its you will see the log in logcat and you will know where to start debugging and thanks for accepting

Comment: in this line `int id_menu_one = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string", this.getPackageName());` `id_menu_one` is always 0. But the `item` contain the right values. it's as if it doesn't convert to int.

Comment: `int resourceID = 
    this.getResources().getIdentifier("resource name", "resource type as mentioned in R.java",this.getPackageName());`, this is the activity context. resource name is string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some String Resource is missing. Make sure `@string/thumbnail_desc` and `@string/c_desc` exist in your `strings.xml` file.